# How can you make tensorflow model from data that contains array next to the other elements?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Let's assume we have such `x_data` to our array

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x_data = np.array([[ [1,2] , [3,4] , [5,6] ], [ [7,8], [9,10], [11,12] ]])
```

then the `input_shape` of `x_data` is `(3, 2)`, that is clear, let's step further.

**We want to add an additional array of n elements to each of the most inner scope, that will look as follows**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x_data = np.array([[ [1,2,[n elements]] , [3,4,[...]] , [5,6,[...]] ], [ [7,8,[...]], [9,10,[...]], [11,12,[...]] ]])
```

**Is this possible? How to make right keras.model with this data? Which is the right shape of the input data?**

**If this is not possible, then how should we approach such problem?**

Comment: How many elements? What would be the input shape?

Comment: If you are asking about the `n`, than it doesn't really matter, but lets suppose - 3;
And so the input shape - is the exact thing I want to know if such shape would exist and would be valid for keras.layers.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, that's not even a valid Numpy shape

Comment: Is it even not possible with ragged tensors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy function `concatenate`, which allows to concatenate two arrays along an axis.
Find more info in the [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

In your case:

```
x_data = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
z_data = [[10, 20, 30, 40], [50, 60, 70, 80], [100, 200, 300, 400]]
ar = np.concatenate((x_data, z_data), axis=1)
```